# Медленно рисуется сетка в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

У меня есть функция, которая отрисовывает координатную сетку из 20 линий на плоскости с помощью цикла for и сдвигом координат. Проблема в том, что на моем устройстве сетка прорисовывается не сразу, а последовательно, будто между итерациями цикла есть какая-то задержка. В итоге сетка рисуется около 10-15 секунд каждый раз(нужно часто сбрасывать дисплей  к пустой сетке и каждый раз это отнимает много времени). На других устройствах, даже на старых ПК 2000-х годов сетка отрисовывается мнгновенно и не требует каких то больших ресурсов, но на моем, довольно мощном ноутбуке это происходит очень долго. Может ли быть связано с настройками Visual Studio 2019? На всякий случай приложу и сам код.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

float const xmax = 10, xmin = -1, ymax = 10, ymin = -1;
int const widht = 600, height = 600;



vector<float> coordinates;

void createlines(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


void drawBoard()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.64, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3ub(250, 250, 250);
    for (byte i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        glVertex2f(xmin + i, ymin);
        glVertex2f(xmin + i, ymax);

    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

        glVertex2f(xmin, ymin + i);
        glVertex2f(xmax, ymin + i);
    }
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(4);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, ymin);
    glVertex2f(0, ymax);
    glVertex2f(xmin, 0);
    glVertex2f(xmax, 0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}



void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.64, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int c = 0;


void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        c++;
        if (c <= 3){
            float x0 = x * (xmax - xmin) / widht + xmin;
            float y0 = (height - y) * (ymax - ymin) / height + ymin;
            glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
            glPointSize(10);
            glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2f(x0, y0);
            coord_x.push_back(x0);
            coord_y.push_back(y0);
            glEnd();
            glFlush(); };
    };
    

    if ((button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glFlush();
        drawBoard();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello world");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawBoard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кроме `glFlush();`, вам бы почитать про современный OpenGL. Сетку можно один раз закатать в VBO (вершинный буфер), а потом рисовать оттуда чуть ли не мгновенно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat нельзя использовать другой OpenGL, задачи в ВУЗе только на этом :/

Comment: `glDrawArrays` даже в старом GL2 есть. (В "современном" `glBegin` убрали, а `glDrawArrays` оставили. Поэтому любой современный туториал будет советовать использовать его, или что-то подобное.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat делал и с ним, все равно отрисовывается последовательно

Comment: Покажите код с ним?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://codeshare.io/ZJZLAn

Comment: Так, и вы хотите сказать, что тут линии рисуются последовательно? А можете видео записать, как это выглядит?

Comment: А зачем вы показываете лишний код вообще? `createlines` нигде не используется. Приведите пожалуйста минимальный воспроизводимый код, без лишней шелухи.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пока нет возможости записать видео, но белые линии сетки рисуются последовательно(2 линии в секунду)